# i want to make recyclerview items selectable and swap 2 selected items on buttonclick

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to allow selection for 2 items in RecyclerView and on the button click i want to swap those items with each other and maintain(save) arraylist of changed RecyclerView...

I tried doing this with `itemTouchListener` and some other custom classes and adapters but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Hi shubham, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: post some code what u have tried so far